# how to make 2 versions of author page at WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, customization, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to make 2 different types of WordPress author profile. One is written in English and another is written in Japanese. To do this, I add a custom user field.  For example, 'biography' for the English version and '経歴' for the Japanese version.

At *admin > user panel*, each author can register their info in both languages, then in the English version author page I display `get_the_author_meta( 'biography_en', $userID );`,  and in the Japanese version author page I display `get_the_author_meta( 'biography_ja', $userID );`.

How could I connect a URL and 2 author page?

Currently, I display `{root URL}/author/{username}` for the English version. I want to display the Japanese version as `{root URL}/author/{username}/ja`.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use author.php template for adding rule

```
if ( isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang']=='ja'){
 /*echo JA data*/
}else{
 /*echo EN data*/
}
```

It will be work for url like {root URL}/author/{username}?lang=ja

If you want  '{root URL}/author/{username}/ja' need to use [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

Comment: Nice!! Thank you very much!

Comment: changing by parameter is better I think.